# Как сделать ограничение, чтобы можно было вставить только строку в формате 'ЧЧ.ММ.СС'?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle

Как сделать ограничение через `REGEXPLIKE()`, чтобы можно было вставить только строку в формате `'ЧЧ.ММ.СС'`?

Всего 8 символов, точки тоже считаются.

Comment: `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column, '^([01][0-9])|(2[0-3])\.[0-5][0-9]\.[0-5][0-9]')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
create table t1 (timestr varchar2(8),
    constraint t1chktime check (
        regexp_like (timestr, '^(([01][0-9])|(2[0-3]))\.[0-5][0-9]\.[0-5][0-9]')))
/

insert into t1 values ('23.59.59');

1 row inserted.

insert into t1 values ('24.00.00');

ORA-02290: check constraint (DB.T1CHKTIME) violated
```